# I got a corrupt excel file that is definitely not corrupt. What should I do?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Opening it shows this message:

> We found a problem with some content .xlsx error. Then> The file is
>   corrupt and cannot be opened.

I copied the file. Change the name from filename.xlsx to filename2.xlsx

The file works with no issue.

I am just curious why.

Comment: I've seen it before too. It is even weirder that if you delete the original, and rename the working filename2.xlsx back to filename1.xlsx and open it, it stops working. I never found an explaination as to why it happened, so we settled for just using the renamed file instead.

Comment: Good Question. I have no idea but I think hash conflict with filename and extension. I would love to know the real reason. I'm going to look into it.

Comment: Would you mind adding tags liks the OS and filesystem maybe we get an answer faster that way.

Comment: Oh, also... where is the file stored? Is it on a network share? on a NAS? if network share, what OS is the server? In my case, the file was hosted on a Windows Server 2008 R2 network share, and obviously affected everyone.

Comment: Have you tried Open and Repair?

Comment: doesn't work. Copying the file and reinstering the password works.

Answer (score 0):

I have asked a colleague of mine and here is our answer.

The Header of the file could have been written faulty. This makes excel think the file is corrupt because it cannot read its header/meta-data.

Renaming the file to a different name will update the header/meta-data to be correct again. Excel will read it and see no problems with the header/meta-data.

As for the renaming the file back to the original and then having the same problem again could be because its still in the cache or temp of the system and or Excel. Excel will read the file but read the cache or temp instead looking for a file with that name.

Why does this happen? A harddisk or ssd can sometimes make mistakes or maybe the system makes a mistake in which the file is saved / written partly or not good. This can cause a file to become corrupt. There are many more reasons on why a file could get corrupt and how it could be fixed by renaming but this is what we think.